# Need Eclipse Team History for a File

Tags: eclipse, git, git-rewrite-history

I have set up eclipse on a new computer and on the old one I was able to get the entire Git revision history of a file with a history tab of all changes complete with color coded line numbers in margin.

Now I only get Right click -> Team -> Show Local History.

How do I get Team -> Show In History back again?

Tried this with different perspectives and adding history view to both Navigator and Package Explorer views.

I can get revision history of an entire package resource but need it for just files.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure your file is part of a git repo you have cloned locally (there should be a `.git` subfolder at the root of your project)

And you need to [share that project with Git](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide/Sharing) (Eclipse will recognized an existing Git repo)

[image: https://wiki.eclipse.org/images/8/88/03-SelectRepositoryTypeGit.png]